# Is there a formula for the sequence of non-quadratic numbers? (e.g. $2,3,5,6,7,8,10,...$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis

Hello fellow mathematicians,
I need to find a formula for the sequence of numbers that can't be written as the square of a natural number (need it for proofing some subsequence stuff). Has anyone got an (if possible simple) idea on this? Quadratic numbers can be written as
$k^2$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$
but i need to find the exact opposite.

Comment: $1$ should not be on your list.  See [A000037](http://oeis.org/A000037) for general information, including formulas for the $n^{th}$ term in the sequence.

Comment: @Derivative It's something like that, but your formula has $a_1=0$. Also it has $a_4=4$.

Comment: @lulu omg lol you're right might be just braindead

Answer (score 0):

Whether a number $x$ is an integer or not can be encoded using the floor and ceiling functions as $\lceil{x}\rceil-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$. This is $0$ if $x$ is an integer and $1$ otherwise.

So, the sequence could be defined recursively as follows: $a_1=2$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+2-\lceil{\sqrt{a_n+1}}\rceil+\lfloor{\sqrt{a_n+1}}\rfloor$.

Comment: Is there any possible way to find a sequence without the floor and ceiling function? I have to proof that the sequence $a_n:=\sqrt{n}-\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ has the accumulation points 1 and 0 and i figured the limit of the subsequence of the quadratic numbers is 0 and the limit of the subsequence of the non-quadratic numbers is 1. I used $k^2$ as the integer of the subsequence of the perfect squares with $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and this worked but using this stuff with the floor function seems kinda complicated. Do you have any other idea for that problem? Please no solution, maybe just a tipp.